# XSLT param identity transform without input XML

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters

I'm trying this for days and no success. I have following XSLT which doesn't take any input XML, but has one param as XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="products">
        <products author="Jesper">
            <product id="p1">
                <name>Delta</name>
                <price>800</price>
                <stock>4</stock>
                <country>Denmark</country>
            </product>
            <product id="p2">
                <name>Golf</name>
                <price>1000</price>
                <stock>5</stock>
                <country>Germany</country>
            </product>
            <product id="p3">
                <name>Alfa</name>
                <price>1200</price>
                <stock>19</stock>
                <country>Germany</country>
            </product>
            <product id="p4">
                <name>Foxtrot</name>
                <price>1500</price>
                <stock>5</stock>
                <country>Australia</country>
            </product>
            <!-- p5 is a brand new product -->
            <product id="p5">
                <name>Tango</name>
                <price>1225</price>
                <stock>3</stock>
                <country>Japan</country>
            </product>
        </products>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="initial">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$products / @*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="products">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="dateUpdated">
      <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()" />
    </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$products / @*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is example from [here](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity) I just used input XML as param.
My question is how to do identity transform on XSLT param and make this transformation work?

Comment: Is this parameter hard-coded into your stylesheet? If yes, why is it necessary to transform it (within the same stylesheet)?

Comment: It actually comes as external parameter, this was just an example it was easier to test like that

Comment: Yeah well, if it comes as a parameter, then it comes as a string, not as XML. I understand from your other question that you are aware of that, but this question makes little sense on its own. Perhaps it would be better to pass a path to a file as the parameter?

Comment: Note also that in this particular example, copying would be more suitable than the identity transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make the following changes to get your XSLT 2.0 transformation to work:

1. Add `as="node()"` to the `xsl:param`.
2. Match the root element of the (ignored) input XML and
   `<xsl:apply-templates select="$products"/>` from there to get
   started on the param XML.
3. Remove `$products` from the `xs:apply-templates` of your other
   templates.
4. Remove `name="initial"` from your identity template.

**Then, your XSLT 2.0 transformation with the above updates:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="products" as="node()">
    <products author="Jesper">
      <product id="p1">
        <name>Delta</name>
        <price>800</price>
        <stock>4</stock>
        <country>Denmark</country>
      </product>
      <product id="p2">
        <name>Golf</name>
        <price>1000</price>
        <stock>5</stock>
        <country>Germany</country>
      </product>
      <product id="p3">
        <name>Alfa</name>
        <price>1200</price>
        <stock>19</stock>
        <country>Germany</country>
      </product>
      <product id="p4">
        <name>Foxtrot</name>
        <price>1500</price>
        <stock>5</stock>
        <country>Australia</country>
      </product>
      <!-- p5 is a brand new product -->
      <product id="p5">
        <name>Tango</name>
        <price>1225</price>
        <stock>3</stock>
        <country>Japan</country>
      </product>
    </products>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="dateUpdated">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$products"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce the desired output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products dateUpdated="2014-12-09T06:38:15.8-05:00" author="Jesper">
   <product id="p1">
      <name>Delta</name>
      <price>800</price>
      <stock>4</stock>
      <country>Denmark</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p2">
      <name>Golf</name>
      <price>1000</price>
      <stock>5</stock>
      <country>Germany</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p3">
      <name>Alfa</name>
      <price>1200</price>
      <stock>19</stock>
      <country>Germany</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p4">
      <name>Foxtrot</name>
      <price>1500</price>
      <stock>5</stock>
      <country>Australia</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p5">
      <name>Tango</name>
      <price>1225</price>
      <stock>3</stock>
      <country>Japan</country>
   </product>
</products>
```

### XSLT 1.0 Solution

OP's transformation was declared to use XSLT 2.0, but for anyone coming later wanting to do this in XSLT 1.0, it is possible via `document('')`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="products">
    <products author="Jesper">
      <product id="p1">
        <name>Delta</name>
        <price>800</price>
        <stock>4</stock>
        <country>Denmark</country>
      </product>
      <product id="p2">
        <name>Golf</name>
        <price>1000</price>
        <stock>5</stock>
        <country>Germany</country>
      </product>
      <product id="p3">
        <name>Alfa</name>
        <price>1200</price>
        <stock>19</stock>
        <country>Germany</country>
      </product>
      <product id="p4">
        <name>Foxtrot</name>
        <price>1500</price>
        <stock>5</stock>
        <country>Australia</country>
      </product>
      <!-- p5 is a brand new product -->
      <product id="p5">
        <name>Tango</name>
        <price>1225</price>
        <stock>3</stock>
        <country>Japan</country>
      </product>
    </products>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="dateUpdated">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')//xsl:param[@name='products']/products"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can also run XSLT 2.0 transformations by calling a named template, and not having to pass in a dummy XML document.

Comment: I was doing it that way, that is why I had name="initial"

Comment: Could you take a look at this question, this is my real use case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379248/xslt-transform-without-input-xml-with-saxon-parse

Comment: You can still move `name="initial"` over to the new `<xsl:template match="/">` if you'd like.